# InvokeOnMainThread doesn't work with `method group`

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await

> **NOTE**: I found a workaround to my problem even before asking the
>   question, but I'm still wondering why it behave like this.

I'm doing an usual xamarin.iOS application, using `async/await`, `Mvvm`, ... nothing fancy on the technology side.

I found out that the following code (using a `method group`) wasn't working:

```cs
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.PropertyName != "MyProperty")
        return;
    InvokeOnMainThread (tableViewController.TableView.ReloadData);
};
```

If I put a breakpoint on `InvokeOnMainThread`, I can see the exception:

[image]

But the same code with a `lambda expression` works just fine.

```cs
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.PropertyName != "MyProperty")
        return;
    InvokeOnMainThread (() => tableViewController.TableView.ReloadData ());
};
```

A part of me is suspecting a bug, another part is already blaming my ignorance. Anyone knows which part is right ?

Comment: I assume `ReloadData` returns void as expected? It doesn't return say.. int or bool?

Comment: yes, it's void. Both syntax are valid and compile just fine. One is running in the UI thread, the other not.

Comment: Strange.. you wouldn't expect it to behave differently with an Action or an Expression. I'm not a Mono developer.. but I can't even find proper documentation on the InvokeOnMainThread method.. or any proper explanation of how each overload works. From a Windows developer.. I would not expect it to perform differently.

Comment: don't worry too much, as a Mono developer myself I don't expect a different behavior neither :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look more closely at the exception you get, you'll see this:

```
tableViewController.TableView   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException [...]
```

The problem is that you're fetching the TableView property (which has to be done in order to create a delegate to the ReloadData method) on the background thread.

Comment: THIS make sense ! there's in fact a `UIApplication.EnsureUIThread();` in the `TableView` getter.

Answer (score 0):

tableView is UI element, you cannot access to ui element(or his properties) not from not UI thread.